# Spring Framework 3.1.1 incompatibility

Tags: spring, jdbc, jmx, spring-webflow

We are using very old version of spring 2.0.6 in our code, We were trying to upgrade it to the latest 3.1.1.RELEASE, But facing issues.

First, The latest version of spring artifacts mentioned below are 2.0.8:
spring-jmx
spring-dao
spring-support

Where are these in new SPRING?

Second, Somehow, it seems that our code is not compatible with these 3 artifacts:
spring-beans -3.1.1
spring-jdbc -3.1.1
spring-context -3.1.1

What are the changes in these latest versions compared to old version (2.5.6)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend to do it step by step:

- upgrad to Spring 2.5
- then to Spring 3.0 (the most changed)
- and then to 3.1

in Spring 3.0 are some libary changes. But I think you will find some stack overflow question on how to upgrad from 2.5 to 3.0.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you know weather spring maintains any information regarding which spring(jmx/remoting/context) jar are compatible with which spring(core/beans) jar version

Comment: you should always use the same version for all the spring core jars. If you do not find any information which spring version the  "external" libs requires, than the last source can be the maven repository.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. Got one useful link, which tells what are the changes in different spring versions . :)
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/new-in-2.html

Answer (score 0):

Check Spring-tx module and the corresponding versions.